# Laravel - Display No for 0 and Yes for 1 on index view blade

Tags: laravel

I am developing a project in Laravel-5.8.

Controller

```
public function index()
{
        $identities = AppraisalIdentity::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index')->with('identities', $identities);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
   <tbody>
  @foreach($identities as $key => $identity)
    <td>
      {{$key+1}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{$identity->appraisal_name ?? '' }}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{ $identity->is_current ?? '' }}
    </td>
  @endforeach
```

What I want to achieve is that when is_current is 0, it should display **No in red colour** and when is_current is 1, should display **Yes in green colour**.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Blade unescaped bracket notation for this to add a css span with style or class like this:

```
{!! $identity->is_current ? "<span class='green'>Yes</span>" : "<span class='red'>No</span>" !!}
```

Where red and green are style classes for your colors.

Comment: The end of your answer states you need to close with }}, keep in mind this needs to be a single }.

Comment: Nice catch @David Kooijman!  I've edited the typo, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Laravel [blade's if statement](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#if-statements):

```php
<td>
    @if ($identity->is_current)
        <span style="color: green;">Yes</span>
    @else
        <span style="color: red;">No</span>
    @endif
</td>
```